# Splitting lines and deleting segments in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, line, splitting

I have created a line that I now want to partially delete. I tried to do it with "split feature"  but it didn't work. The wohle line deleted automatically when using this function.

As you can see in the picture, I want to delete something in the middle of the line (between the red marks).

[image]

Comment: I'd use the node tool to create vertexes where you want to split the line.  I'd also turn on vertex snapping.  Then use the split tool.  I prefer the one that's on the Advanced Digitizing toolbar.

Comment: @John thenk you, I will try it out

Comment: Start editing your line feature class, select the line.  Split the line using the split tool.  https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/fi/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#split-features